# Markdown on gVim

Tags: vim, text-editors, gvim, text-formatting, markdown

I want to edit my `Markdown.md` file with gVim displaying the formatting (rich-text) and also editing that is converting the text as I type in the markdown format.

Is it possible to do that with `vim` or `gVim`?

I'm on Fedora 25 Beta.
Previously I used Evernote on Windows to type in and view rich-text. I don't want to rely on Firefox addons to view markdown. I installed and used `zim` for a while to view and type markdown but it doesn't support the formatting fully, and as I use `vim` a lot I want it to render markdown either through plugins or something in console or graphical editions.

Answer (score 2):

Vim ships with syntax scripts for Markdown (and there are alternatives on the Internet), and should even automatically detect most Markdown files.

As Vim is a text editor, the rendering is limited to the fixed-width font and font attributes available in the terminal (GVIM supports some more [colors and styles], but otherwise is pretty similar).

This is how Markdown looks in my personal Vim:

[image]

#### Syntax

Markdown syntax is deliberately lightweight, so you can easily type in the formatting parts as-is. Plugins like [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) can help a bit with that.

Comment: Thanks. Do you use the default syntax files only? If it is not the case, could you please provide sources to make it render Markdown files as depicted in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, that's just the default syntax script. The actual colors depend on your chosen `:colorscheme`, naturally.